# Visual Studio For Database Professionals 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, database-project, datadude

Anyone know any a few good references for getting familiar with the SQL Server 2008 Database projects?  I am getting a bit overwhelmed and would love to find a walk through for putting this project type to good use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at AdventureWorks (I'd assume some of that stuff is in .dbproj format)?

Answer (score 1):

You could do worse than read:

- [Gert Drapers's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/gertd/default.aspx)
- [Product Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833253.aspx)

I know, I know, no one likes to read the instructions, but I've just started using these myself and skimming through the documentation has helped a lot.